# Using external drive for PHP storage

Tags: php, server, storage

I have a PHP application, running on a centos box, that stores a large amount of user-uploaded files.

Right now I am storing the data in a folder /uploads, but I am running out of space on the server.

I have the option of adding storage drives of 100GB. For example, drives /dev/XXXX, /dev/YYYY, and /dev/ZZZZ each have 100 GB.

I would like to know the best way to store user-uploaded files across multiple drives. Is there a Centos directive that can join drives into one available space for PHP? Or should I just have PHP upload files to the first drive, and when fills up, have it save to the second, etc?

Thanks!
Ben

Comment: you're asking for opinions, which are explicitly off-topic. drives are cheap. if you run out of space on one, buy a bigger one. you can get 4TB for <$200CA these days.

Comment: Linux (including CentOS) generally doesn't use drive letters. What do you mean by "drives f, g and h"?

Comment: @Marc B No, I am asking what is the correct way to use PHP to store data across multiple drives.

Comment: php couldn't care less about the storage structure on the os. it just sees directories and files. how those directories/files are arranged is up to you.

Comment: I updated my question. I don't think my question was clear.

Answer (score 2):

[Logical Volume Manager (LVM)](https://jee-appy.blogspot.in/2016/10/logical-volume-manager-lvm.html) is a tool to easily expand or combine multiple hard drives into a single pool of storage and makes it easy to dynamically resize and create new partitions, even without restarting the process or without removing the volume. You need to do following steps:

- Installation of `lvm2`.
- Make a new partition and set the type of the partition as LVM.
- Create physical volume
- Create Volume group (VG)
- Create a Logical Volume (LV)
- Create a file system on the logical volume group that is just created. That it is.

[Here](https://jee-appy.blogspot.in/2016/10/logical-volume-manager-lvm.html) you can find complete procedure for it. For Live demo of procedure, watch [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WG1tgL7zyC8).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LVM (Logical Volume Manager)](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-lvm.html) that enables you to create a logical volume from multiple physical volumes , but i would advise against it as if a hard drive fails, the whole logical volume might be compromised.

Have a look at [AWS S3 storage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html), it might do the job for your project.

Comment: Here is a link from server fault to make a LVM http://serverfault.com/questions/692724/how-can-i-create-one-large-partiton-over-two-drives-in-centos